# Azure pipelines failing on specific deploy jobs

Tags: azure, azure-pipelines

On only two of my pipeline jobs I keep getting this error:

```
##[error]No hosted parallelism has been purchased or granted. To request a free parallelism grant, please fill out the following form https://aka.ms/azpipelines-parallelism-request
```

This doesnt happen on any of the other jobs in the pipeline.

[image]

This only started happening on 9th of February.

I've seen in the past that public projects were stopped from using parallelizm in pipelines (which I dont even think I'm using). But my project has been using Azure Pipelines before this was implemented, and these changes were not supposed to affect existing projects.

Is there a reason this has started happening recently? I cannot re-start the jobs either, the same error occurs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Azure pipelines failing on specific deploy jobs

It seems that the hosted pipeline parallelism disabled (earlier working) after 8th Feb for some customers.

To resolve this issue, I recommend you need to create a technical support ticket from Azure Portal if you have [Azure support plans](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/support/plans/) to ask product team to resolve this in banckend.

Comment: Hi I have done this and am awaiting from the Microsoft support team to find out why my pipelines were disabled with absolutely no notice.